# cannot upgrade umbraco using nuget in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, umbraco7

I am upgrading Umbraco from 7.4.3 to 7.6.3.

I installed Umbraco 7.4.3 using nuget in VS2013. Now when I try to upgrade using nuget( Update-Package UmbracoCms),  I get the following error in VS2013:

**The 'UmbracoCms 7.6.3' package requires NuGet client version '3.4.4' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.12.0.817'**

*I checked [here](https://www.nuget.org/) and it seem to me that NuGet client version '3.4.4' is for vs2015 **only** but I am using VS2013.*

Is there any solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line `nuget.exe` 4.1.0 or higher (3.5.0 isn't able to use MSBuild 12) to perform the necessary commands (`nuget.exe update` to update the package, `nuget.exe restore` whenever you clone the project / do CI builds). But then you'll need to disable the VS-integrated NuGet restore.

Other option is to migrate to a newer version of visual studio to get VS-integrated support for new NuGet features.

Comment: thanks for looking into the problem. Could you please explain step by step to achieve the first option.Many Thanks.

Comment: I am getting this error when I run nuget.exe:     Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open the Visual Studio
Options dialog, click on Package Manager node and check 'Allow NuGet to download
 missing packages during build.' You can also give consent by setting the enviro
nment variable 'EnableNuGetPackageRestore' to 'true'.

Comment: You can set `EnableNuGetPackageRestore` as environment variable or add  `<EnableNuGetPackageRestore>true</EnableNuGetPackageRestore>` to a condition-less property group in the csproj file